# Extending EntityFieldQuery. Which variables should I define?

Tags: database

I have been playing around with extending EntityFieldQuery, and I was wondering which variables I should define on the class. I am also a beginner in OOP so this is an experiment.

```
class nodematcher extends EntityFieldQuery
 {
  private $pathtomatch = NULL;
  private $nodestocheck = array();
  private $matchingnode = NULL;
  private $query = NULL;
  private $results = NULL;
  public $nodes = NULL;
  public $path = NULL;
  public $json = NULL;
  public function __construct()
   {
    $this->query = New entityFieldQuery;
    $this->query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->fieldCondition('geoslate_slate_entry_path', 'value', '', '<>');
    $this->results = $this->query->execute();
    foreach($this->results['node'] as $result)
     {
      $this->nodestocheck[] = $result->nid;
     }
    $this->nodes = entity_load('node', $this->nodestocheck);
    return $this->nodes;
   }
  public function lookupfullpath($path)
   {
    foreach($this->nodes as $key => $value)
     {
      $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $value);
      $entry_path = $wrapper->geoslate_slate_entry_path->value();
      if(reset($entry_path) == $path)
       {
        $this->matchingnode[] = $wrapper->nid->value();
       }
     }
    $loadedentities = entity_load('node', $this->matchingnode);
    //$this->json = drupal_json_encode($loadedentities);
    return $loadedentities;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should define whatever variables you need...only you know why you're subclassing `EntityFieldQuery` after all :) Or is that not what you meant? If not could you clarify exactly what you mean? If you mean which methods/members does `EntityFieldQuery` offer to be overridden, just look for `protected` members of the original class. If that's the case this is really just a PHP question, a good read of the [OO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) is a must otherwise you'll just get overwhelmed trying to work out what's going on

Comment: the main reason is readibility. What I am making lends itself better to a constructor and then a series of functions that already have access to entityfieldquery function. I'm hoping this this will be a less verbose way of doing what I want and I will learn a bit of oop in the process :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class nodematcher extends EntityFieldQuery {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->query = New entityFieldQuery;
```

This doesn't make any sense. You are either subclassing `EntityFieldQuery` or you are using a delegate pattern. Doing both makes little sense. What you wanted here is perhaps `parent::__construct` and wherever you used `$this->query` just use `$this`.